# Flash and XML beginner issue

Tags: xml, flash

I´m new to XML and I´ve tried a couple of tutorials but nothing seems to work.

ERROR: URLLoader not defined.

1. Whats wrong with my structure? How should it look like?
2. How can i save a highscore in XML and read it out later?

   ```
   //XML
   public var oLoader= new URLLoader();
   public var oUrl:URLRequest; 

   public function Main() 
   {
       oLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, _oListener);
       LoadData("LoadTest.xml", LoadDataComplete);
   }



   public function _oListener(_tUrl:String, _oListener:Function) 
      {
       oUrl= new URLRequest(_tUrl);
       oLoader.load(oUrl);
      }

   public function LoadDataComplete(_oEvent:Event) 
   {
      var xmlFile:XML = new XML(_oEvent.currentTarget.data);
      //XML_txt.text = xmlFile;

     trace(xmlFile.GroupNode.TextNode[0]); 
     trace(xmlFile.AttributeNode.toXMLString()); 
     trace(xmlFile.AttributeNode.@Id);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

you are missing import statement `import flash.net.*;`

This will include the required URLLoader and URLRequest classes.